# How does aim assist work in Fortnite on console?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

On PS4 and Xbox One, there is an option in the Fortnite settings for aim-assist. Will it have a major impact if I turn it off?

Also, I would like to know how aim assist works in Fortnite.

Answer (score 6):

When aiming with aim-assist your center, where your bullet will hit, follows a little when your target is moving. How much it will affect on your accuracy depends on your skill to aim moving targets. Generally the effect is smaller for more experienced gamers. The only way to find out if there is a major effect in your game is to try to use it and assess if you are generally hitting better or worse. Sometimes aim-assist can also have undesirable effects, for example if you are aiming at an enemy and another enemy player quickly passes your line of sight the aim-assist starts to follow the moving player causing you to miss your original target.

Answer (score -2):

If you aim near the person there zoom in it will move towards the head and it will follow the player until they are out of range

Answer (score -3):

Aim assist is kind of like a built-in aimbot but not very accurate.
When the person who you are shooting at is moving, you automatically look at them.